# How to add a live tile in XAML

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, live-tile

I would like to add live tiles to a listbox in my WP7 application. I would also like to create the list in the XAML, but I am unsure of how to add a LiveTile in this manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no stock control that would represent the tile. However, there is the [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) that includes the **Tile** control. [Here is a guide](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Getting-Started-with-the-Coding4Fun-toolkit-Tile-Control) on how to use it. Obviously, you will have to manage the "live" behavior on your own.